# Number of roots to system of Polynomials

Tags: polynomials

If you have a system of k polynomials of dimension k and degree r is the number of solutions equal to:

k^s?

This appears to be the pattern and intuitively one could argue that each of the s systems can be solved for k solutions which are asymptotically linear and therefore overall there are k*k*k... = k^s solutions.

This is absolutely non rigorous and unjustified. So I guess I'm looking for formal clarification and verification.

Comment: You haven't defined $s$. What is it?

Comment: In any case, Bezout's [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout's_theorem) might turn out to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!